# MongoDB - Replace embedded fields

Tags: database, mongodb, orm, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "6021d4e8de525e00bb3623f1",
    ...otherFields,
    "addonGroups": [
      {
        "_id": "6021d474143dbb00da601e6a",
        ...otherFields,
        "addons": [
          {
            "name": "Nike\t珍珠",
            ...otherFields,
          },
          {
            "name": "Adidas\t椰果",
            ...otherFields,
          },
          
        ]
      }
    ],
    
  }
]
```

I want to replace the `\t` character for whitespace " " on all the addons name field

I have the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "addonGroups.addons.name": {
        $replaceAll: {
          input: "$addonGroups.addons.name",
          find: "\t",
          replacement: " "
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I am getting this error:

> query failed: (Location51746) PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $replaceAll requires that 'input' be a string, found: [["Nike  珍珠", "Adidas   椰果"]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `$map` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      addonGroups: {
        $map: {
          input: "$addonGroups",
          as: "addonGroup",
          in: {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$addonGroup",
              {
                "addons": {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$addonGroup.addons",
                    as: "addon",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$addon",
                        {
                          "name": {
                            $replaceAll: {
                              input: "$$addon.name",
                              find: "\t",
                              replacement: " "
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wRd11yxgULB)

Comment: Thanks a lot, addons do have other fields. Where should I place this last part you added?

Comment: Ya, I have update my answer.

Comment: This works on the playground but when I run this against the DB I get the following 

Error: Unrecognized expression '$replaceAll'

Comment: May I know your MongoDB version? It is available in [version 4.4](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceAll/)

Comment: ah that's the issue. I'm using 4.2.10

Comment: For the MongoDB version 4.4 before, you can look for this [solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JZniQKAYxGB).

Comment: thanks but I forgot the aggregation framework does not write to DB so this is not saving on my database

Comment: @DanielMorales You could add a `"$merge"` stage to the end of the pipeline.

Comment: And also you may have a look on [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).